# Mysql date selection not working

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have this mysql query:

```
$preformatDate=$registroCampaign['ca_lastcapture'];
$query="SELECT * FROM ws_campreplies
        WHERE cr_fk_us_id='$id'
          AND cr_message LIKE '%{$registroCampaign['ca_key1']}%'
          AND cr_time > '$preformatDate'"
```

Both `cr_time` and `ca_lastcapture` are datetime fields.

That being echoed shows this final query result:

```
SELECT *
FROM ws_campreplies
WHERE cr_fk_us_id = '2'
AND cr_message LIKE '%PROMO%'
AND cr_time > '2015-05-28 20:42:37'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

And it selects two rows:

[image: rows]

This selection is not right, as those records have an earlier date than 2015-05-28.

Also, if I change on the query the `>` sign by the opposite sign `<`, it still result on those two records.

Comment: Which datatype has the column `cr_time`?

Comment: Use mysql DATE_FORMAT()

Comment: create your table with data on sqlfiddle.com and show your query output

Comment: Have you tried `AND cr_time > NOW()`

Comment: @Jens it is a Datetime field

Comment: @user3633383 I dont have to filter it by the present time, just by the date and time contained on $preformatDate

Comment: @moffeltje when I set it to DATE_FORMAT as this: $preformatDate=DATE_FORMAT($registroCampaign['ca_lastcapture']); an error emerges: it expects2 parameters,

Comment: @RavinderReddy I am not very fammiliar with that tool, this is what I could get: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4553e/1

Comment: Both cr_time and ca_lastcapture are datetime fields

Comment: try to covert `'2015-05-28 20:42:37'` to a date using str_to_date()

Comment: @moffeltje that right query setted on the PHP does not work. And setts on PHPMyAdmin says syntax error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '15:30:21) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: @Jens Both cr_time and ca_lastcapture are datetime fields. Anyway I will try to follow your advice, let's see

Comment: Your query seems to be running correctly... all `cr_time`s in your table are less than '2015-05-28 20:42:37' using `>` will not return any results.

Comment: Ok @iroegbu I'm gonna check everyhting

Comment: @iroegbu you are totally right. In some step I missed the ' between $preformatDate, on the query

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: **@Biomehanika**: I strooooooooooooooooooongly believe that your compare condition was `... AND cr_time > '2015-05-**25** 20:42:37'`. [*Proof*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4553e/10)